# Android : Recyclerview cracking animation

Tags: android, animation, android-recyclerview, android-animation

In mac system when we move any files to trash then we can see some effects.

I just want to do that cracking animation when i remove an item from my RecyclerView. I have gone through lot of animations like slid-in, slide-out, zoom-in, zoom-out,fade-in and fade-out. I don't have any idea to implement this. If someone have any idea then please share to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should use notifyItemInserted(pos) and notifyItemRemoved(pos). also check this http://blog.trsquarelab.com/2015/12/creating-custom-animation-in.html

Comment: @VladislavShcherbakov Thank you. But this is not the type of animation i specified in my question.

Comment: If you find solution, please, post it here. Really interesting case.